# The "src / background.js" background script could not be loaded. The manifest could not be loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js

This example creates a Chrome extension, enabling users to right-click on images within a web page, and perform multi-class object detection on them. The extension will will apply a MobileNetV2 classifier to the image, and then print the predicted class on top of the image.

**the problem**:
I'm following the steps but I still can't test this extension

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/chrome-extension

this appears(the error):
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ITsK.jpg][2]
"Archive
~ \ Desktop \ tfjs-examples \ chrome-extension \ dist
Error
The "src / background.js" background script could not be loaded.
The manifest could not be loaded."

The manifest:

```
    {
  "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApAR3gTAUuMUf/nAaIip/Vd2xMAR2Xk+9dqlVruWUdsMXeCGiuECchTmOguyPakqdTTA7Mbyd0RyaU86z63iX350cdyYXzfhLUwecQYIZUFh15c7HhGm8YliGj26voZAkczPB8EnaQtnhUIvTkdrys2/TtQy46bCmZlOTuAwM+xQXf0Yo0GkKCU/+bI/S/e7ZkYD+39Riwj/w/Xv+ipdfAH6clPJ/Xs+cOm+MsydKuR7bB3PermsHiv2LKbEnyS7wn7Vev5Q2pdGRRcMQDnXZwYP5YlrEQEp2xdwM2kIvCh2MOk7J0ULniFUpPpdk7Uy2jD72pCZxT4SiiuAUdMLogQIDAQAB",
  "name": "TF.js mobilenet in a Chrome extension",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Classify images right in your browser using TensorFlow.js and mobilenet.",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["src/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["src/content.js"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
   "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this please? or tell me how can I test / start creating a Chrome extension that will use TensorFlow.js?

Comment: All files and directories of the compiled extension should be inside the directory with manifest.json, because that's the *root* of the extension. Copy or move the files to `dist` directory or stop using this separation as it doesn't seem useful at all in this case.

Comment: Actually all of this is already performed when you compile the extension properly as explained in its readme.